# SwiftUI limit tappable area of picker in form

Tags: forms, swiftui, picker

**I would like to limit the tappable area of the picker in a form to only it's visible area of text (i.e. black rectangle in the picture below)**. Currently whole row can be tappable.

[Screen capture of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfIPT.png)

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rate: String = ""
    @State var units = ["mL/day","mL/hour"]
    @State var unit: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                HStack{
                    Text("Rate")
                    TextField("0", text: $rate)
                    Picker(selection: $unit, label: Text(""), content: {
                        ForEach(0..<units.count, content: { unit in
                            Text(units[unit])
                        })
                    })
                    .frame(width: 100.0)
                    .compositingGroup()
                    .clipped()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110421/how-to-stop-a-swiftui-picker-from-reacting-to-touches-outside-its-visible-area) and try to add `.clipped()` and `.compositingGroup()` but seems not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to redesign the UI a bit. I would recommend this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rate: String = ""
    @State var units = ["mL/day","mL/hour"]
    @State var unit: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Rate")) { // Do This
                    HStack{
                        TextField("0", text: $rate)
                            .background(Color.red)
                        Picker(selection: $unit, label: Text(""), content: {
                            ForEach(0..<units.count, content: { unit in
                                Text(units[unit])
                            })
                        })
                        .frame(width: 100)
                        .clipped()
                        .background(Color.green)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made colored backgrounds for each of the subviews. The issue is not that the whole row is selectable. It is that when you have a `Picker()` in the row, any view that is not itself selectable, in this case the `Text()` triggers the `Picker()`. If you use your code and put a colored background behind the text, you will see what happens. If you tap on the `Picker()` it triggers. If you tap on the `TextField()` you get an insertion point there. But if you tap on the `Text()` it triggers the `Picker()`. The `.compositingGroup` doesn't affect this behavior at all.

I have this exact design in an app, and the solution is to put the text into `Section` with a header, or put the `Text()` in the row above.