# iOS15 - SwiftUI WheelPicker scrollable outside frame and clipped area destructing other interfaces

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have two WheelPickers contained inside a HStack for 'hour' and 'min'.
Each Picker is set within a frame(width: 50, height: 30) and additionally clipped.

In iOS14, it behaved as expected and I could scrolled the 'hour' picker to change the hour and 'minute' picker to change the mins.

HOWEVER in iOS15, the 'minute' wheelpicker is extended beyond the frame width of 50 and overlapped into the 'hour' picker; if I scroll on the 'hour' picker, the *'mins'* value changes (instead of 'hour' value), if I scroll on 'minute' picker, it changes the 'mins' as expected.  If I touch on the far left outside the 'hour' picker, then the 'hour' value changes.

Anyone has the same issue and any workaround for this issue?

I came across a workaround to add 'mask(rectangle()' and tried it, but it did not work on iOS15.

```
    @State private var hour: Int = 0
    @State private var minute: Int = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 3) {
                
                NumberPicker("", selection: $hour
                                 , startValue: 0
                                 , endValue: 23
                                 , pickerSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
                )

                Text("hr")
                
                NumberPicker("", selection: $minute
                                 , startValue: 0
                                 , endValue: 59
                                 , pickerSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
                )

                Text("min")

            } // HStack
            
        } // VStack

    }

}
```

```
struct NumberPicker: View {
    
    let startValue: Int
    let endValue: Int
    let pickerSize: CGSize
    let title: String
    
    @Binding var selection: Int
    @State var value: Int = 0
    
    init(_ title: String = ""
         , selection: Binding<Int>
         , startValue: Int = 0
         , endValue: Int
         , pickerSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 30)
    ) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.title = title
        self.startValue = startValue
        self.endValue = (endValue + 1)
        self.pickerSize = pickerSize
        
        self._value = State(initialValue: selection.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(title, selection: $value) {
            
            ForEach(startValue..<endValue, id: \.self) { currentValue in
                
                Text("\(currentValue)")
                    .tag(currentValue)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
        .frame(width: pickerSize.width, height: pickerSize.height)
        .clipped(antialiased: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `NumberPicker` try adding `compositingGroup` just before `clipped(...)` as:

```
.compositingGroup()
.clipped(antialiased: true)
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog, you saved my day!  It works like a charm!

Comment: Curious, why does this fix the problem? Thank you @workingdog, it helped me out!

Comment: Thanks @workingdog. That fixed the issue but now I’m having the same thing happen again with the 15.1 release as well as 15.2 beta.  Any fix this time?

Comment: Did submit feedback to apple about this issue - feedback ID - FB9750284

Comment: Hi, Prasanth, I posted a fix for iOS 15 here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068532/3942719

Answer (score 11):

In iOS 15.1 there doesn't seem to be any workaround for this, so I rolled my own using `UIViewRepresentable`. The example is made for my use with `Double` but you can easily adapt it for yours.

As well as being able to have multiple components in a single wheel picker, you can also stack them horizontally in an `HStack` without problem:

**Usage**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selections1: [Double] = [5, 10]
    
    private let data1: [[Double]] = [
        Array(stride(from: 0, through: 60, by: 1)),
        Array(stride(from: 0, through: 60, by: 1))
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                MultiWheelPicker(selections: self.$selections1, data: data1)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                MultiWheelPicker(selections: self.$selections1, data: data1)
                    .frame(width: 150)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

**View**

```
struct MultiWheelPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    var selections: Binding<[Double]>
    let data: [[Double]]
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MultiWheelPicker.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiWheelPicker>) -> UIPickerView {
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        
        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIPickerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiWheelPicker>) {
        for comp in selections.indices {
            if let row = data[comp].firstIndex(of: selections.wrappedValue[comp]) {
                view.selectRow(row, inComponent: comp, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        var parent: MultiWheelPicker
      
        init(_ pickerView: MultiWheelPicker) {
            parent = pickerView
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return parent.data.count
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return parent.data[component].count
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 48
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return String(format: "%02.0f", parent.data[component][row])
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            parent.selections.wrappedValue[component] = parent.data[component][row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to note for `Double` implementation, watch out for binary floating point problems in `data[comp].firstIndex` comparisons, I had to make some adjustments in my production version.

Comment: If you are looking for something that uses only single-value pickers, you can check out [my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70328016/13737173) based on [Steve M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69842277/13737173).

Comment: This seems still the only way to limit the scrollable area of a Picker in SwiftUI and the most important peace of code seems to be: picker.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

Answer (score -2):

I added `.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())` to the Picker view and solved this problem in my iOS 15 code.

Comment: I found that I had a few Pickers that were operating outside of their expected tap-zone when I was using their default, menu appearance.
Once I specified what type of Picker it should be, such as the 'menu', then this solved my problem.
i.e. 
          .pickerStyle(.menu)